# Transferring list of files from android to PC

Tags: android, file-transfer

I am new to android and am writing an app to copy all document files into my PC programmatically. I have the list of files in folders  with me (Currently in a listview). All I need to know is how to copy each file into my PC. Once copied, how to retrieve them back? I am sure that I need to code a server side program in my PC as well, But a little concerned on where to start and how. Below is the android code snippet.

```
public class DocsList extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
CheckBox ChkSelectAll;
ListView DocsList;
Button Backup, Reset, GoBack;
TextView textview;
String[] FileNames;
int k = 0;
public List<String> myList;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    myList = new ArrayList<String>();
    setContentView(R.layout.docslist);
    ChkSelectAll = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.SelectAllDocscheckBox);
    DocsList     = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.DocsList);
    Backup       = (Button)findViewById(R.id.BackupDocs);
    Reset        = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ResetDocs);
    GoBack       = (Button)findViewById(R.id.GoBackDocs);

    String dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File f = new File(dir);
    ArrayList<String> files = getListofDocs(f);
    ArrayAdapter<String> PhoneAdptr = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_selectable_list_item,files);
    DocsList.setAdapter(PhoneAdptr);
    boolean NetState = isNetworkConnected(this);
    if (NetState == true) {
        // Code yet to be written
    }
    else {
        // Code yet to be written
    }
}
private boolean isNetworkConnected(Context context) {
      ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
      NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
      if (ni == null) {
       // There are no active networks.
       return false;
      } else
       return true;
     }

public ArrayList<String> getListofDocs(File parentdir) {
    ArrayList<String> infiles = new ArrayList<String>();
    File[] files = parentdir.listFiles();
    if (files != null) {
        for(File file : files)
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                infiles.addAll(getListofDocs(file));
            }
            else {
                if (file.getName().endsWith("doc") || file.getName().endsWith("DOC")   || 
                        file.getName().endsWith("docx") || file.getName().endsWith("DOCX") ||
                        file.getName().endsWith("htm") || file.getName().endsWith("HTM")   ||
                        file.getName().endsWith("html") || file.getName().endsWith("HTML") ||
                        file.getName().endsWith("txt") || file.getName().endsWith("TXT")   ||
                        file.getName().endsWith("pdf") || file.getName().endsWith("PDF")) {
                    infiles.add(file.toString());
                }
            }
        }

    return infiles;
}   
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == GoBack) {
        Intent Back = new Intent(DocsList.this, CloudStorage.class);
        startActivity(Back);
        finish();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Without having some kind of program/server PC side to receive the data, this isn't a simple task. Unless of course you have some kind of samba share set up on your network, in which case, you could just copy the files to there and have them accessed from both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made use of Dropbox to store my files. Thanks all for your help. I am still working on the retrieval though.